# Div no whitespaces at edges and between divs

Tags: css, html, web

I want it so that there are absolutely not white spaces at all. Non on the edges and nothing between the objects. I've tried everything but so far This is as close as I've got:

```
  <div style="float: left; width:100%; "> <HR SIZE="130" COLOR="#262626" WIDTH="100%">

  <img style="position:absolute;left:10;top:8;" src="logo.png">
</div>

<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:75%; position:fixed; left:0;top:0;overflow:hidden;"></div>

<HR SIZE="20" COLOR="#262626" WIDTH="100%">
```

Comment: Have you considered setting the box model attributes like margin?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but you are missing units in the style for the image, it should be `style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:8px;"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/FCvyh/2/

Add this css

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
hr {
  margin:0;
}
```

I guess you are not using a css reset, correct? The browser adds the random margins.